# Why does this test succeed regardless whether an exception is thrown or not?

Tags: java, junit

When I remove the try/catch it works but cannot test negative test

```
  public class TileCombinationSetsTest {
    
    @Test public void testTileCombinations() {
        
        new TileCombinationSets();
        
        assertEquals(TileCombinationSets.tileCombinations(1).size(), 7);
        assertEquals(TileCombinationSets.tileCombinations(2).size(), 42);
        assertEquals(TileCombinationSets.tileCombinations(3).size(), 210);
        assertEquals(TileCombinationSets.tileCombinations(4).size(), 840);
        assertEquals(TileCombinationSets.tileCombinations(5).size(), 2520);
        assertEquals(TileCombinationSets.tileCombinations(6).size(), 5040);
        assertEquals(TileCombinationSets.tileCombinations(7).size(), 5040);
        
        try {
            TileCombinationSets.tileCombinations(4);
            fail("Exceptions expected");
        }
        catch(Throwable e) {}
    }       
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand what your actual question is. What part is giving you trouble? What are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: no, the code above doesnt throw any exceptions so i would expect fail to be called but it doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JUnit a test fails when the test method throws an exception (or an other Throwable). JUnit's test runner catches the exception and reports the test as failed. On the other hand the test runner considers a test to be successful when the test method finishes without throwing an exception. Statements like `assertEquals` and `fail` throw an [AssertionError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html).

In your test `fail("Exceptions expected")` is throwing an [AssertionError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html). which is immediately caught and and therefore the test method `testTileCombinations` doesn't throw an exception. Now for JUnit it looks like the method was executed successfully and therefore it considers the test to be successful.

If you want to test that `TileCombinationSets.tileCombinations(4)` throws an exception then you can use JUnit's [assertThrows](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThrows(java.lang.Class,%20org.junit.function.ThrowingRunnable))

```
assertThrows(
  Exception.class, // you can be more specific here
  () -> TileCombinationSets.tileCombinations(4)
);
```

If you want to test that `TileCombinationSets.tileCombinations(4)` doesn't throw an exception then you simply execute it. (JUnit will report the test as failed if it throws an exception and successful otherwise.)

```
 @Test
 public void testTileCombinations() {
    ...

    TileCombinationSets.tileCombinations(4);
}
```

Comment: in the code above, the line with the fail should not be reached...what i am saying is whether or not the fail line is reached, the test always succeeds...the test i am trying to do is to ensure the method i am testing with an invalid argument throws an exception....which it does...but when it doesnt throw an exception...it still passes the test which is not what i was expecting

Comment: If testTileCombinations throws an exception it is still caught and you have the same problem: the test method does not throw an exception and therefore JUnit considers the test to be successful.

Comment: I dont know why this is so difficult .....    i want the test to pass when an exception is thrown ..... i want the test to fail if the exception is NOT thrown

Comment: It's not difficult. I extended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the part

```java
TileCombinationSets.tileCombinations(4)
```

throws an exception the second time it is executed.
You could print the stacktrace of the exception to see if an exception is thrown.

Without knowing what TileCombinationSets.tileCombinations(int x) does its hard to say.
If possible could you post the method?

Answer (score 0):

You should generally not catch `Throwable` but `Exception` instead. `Throwable` also includes subclasses of `Error`, which are critical errors concerning that Java Runtime Environment itself (like `OutOfMemoryError`), from which a program should not attempt to recover because it puts the program into an undefined state.

As it happens, the `AssertionError` that is thrown by the `fail()` method in your example

```
        try {
            TileCombinationSets.tileCombinations(4);
            fail("Exceptions expected");
        }
        catch(Throwable e) {}
```

also extends `Error`.

So by changing your code to

```
        try {
            TileCombinationSets.tileCombinations(4);
            fail("Exceptions expected");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
```

it should behave as intended, as long as the exceptions thrown by your `tileCombinations()` method only extend `Exception` (which they should, as it is bad practice to extend `Error` yourself).